# Exceptional error while consuming web service on android

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, exception

Right now i have used SOAP method to consume web service from android eclipse.

I need to get input from edittext and display the proper values,which means to call the web service and return the result.

After emulator getting  run,it shown as "ERROR:java.lang.RuntimeException:Cannot serialize 0004".How to over come this error.

Here is my code,please find

**screen.java**

```
public class X_classActivity extends Activity 
{
    private EditText edit;
    private Button btn; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
         btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                      fun();
             }
         });
   }

private void fun()
{
    //getSOAPResponse() method returns SOAP Response
    SoapObject soapResponseObject = getSOAPResponse(edit.getText());
}

public SoapObject getSOAPResponse(GetChars search)
{
    SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "GetName");
    soapObject.addProperty("str", search);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new      HttpTransportSE("http://122.248.240.105:234/Service1.asmx?WSDL");
    try 
    {
         androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/GetName", envelope);//call the eb service Method
         Object result = envelope.getResponse();
         System.out.println(" " + result.toString());
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2)).setText(""+result.toString());
    } 
    catch (Exception E) 
    {
         E.printStackTrace();
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2)).setText("ERROR:"    + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
    }
    return soapObject;
   }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
06-01 18:39:56.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(932): No keyboard for id 0
06-01 18:39:56.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(932): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-01 18:40:00.510: W/System.err(932): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 0004
06-01 18:40:00.520: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:661)
06-01 18:40:00.520: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:645)
06-01 18:40:00.520: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:614)
06-01 18:40:00.520: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:598)
06-01 18:40:00.520: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:655)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:579)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:192)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:74)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:58)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at com.x.x.x.X_classActivity.getSOAPResponse(X_classActivity.java:57)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at com.x.x.x.X_classActivity.fun(X_classActivity.java:45)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at com.x.x.x.X_classActivity.access$0(X_classActivity.java:41)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at com.x.x.x.X_classActivity$1.onClick(X_classActivity.java:36)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 18:40:00.530: W/System.err(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-01 18:40:00.540: W/System.err(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-01 18:40:00.540: W/System.err(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-01 18:40:00.540: W/System.err(932):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**web method**

```
 public class GetName {
public String GetName(String str){
    return(str);
}    }
```

Thanks a lot!!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are doing something wrong in this line,

```
androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/GetName", envelope);//call the eb service Method
```

I think the 1st argument is wrong. Please see the following code, it works fine for me. Also please export the dependencies hen you build the project. Sometimes it will help you.

```
    private String METHOD_NAME = "";
    // our webservice method name
    private String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.travel_ceylon.web.org";
    // Here package name in webservice with reverse order.
    private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
    // NAMESPACE + method name
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.177.130:8080/Travel_Ceylon_Central_Web_Service/services/Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service?wsdl";

    // you must use ipaddress here, don’t use Hostname or localhost

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String city = "Matara";
        String im = "Galle Face";

        METHOD_NAME = "getLongitude_City";
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("city", city);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Object result = envelope.getResponse();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCityLongitude)).setText(city
                    + " Longitude is : " + result.toString());

        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCityLongitude)).setText("ERROR:"
                    + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
        }
```